# How do I update the browser of the Sony ebook reader PRS-T1?

Tags: updates, 2.2-froyo, browser

I've an old PRS-T1 ebook reader that is still a very good reader. Occasionally I use the browser that is included, but this is very outdated (based on Android 2.2) and often gives errors about security certificates and other errors.
I've rooted this device so I think that it might be possible to manually update the browser for a smoother browsing experience.
Is there a way to update the system browser or install a similar browser (apk) that is e-ink screen friendly?